# Sub entities in solr

Tags: search, solr, lucene

I'm using solr to index an entity which has indefinite number of related entities

Table 1

id name
1 | aa
2 | bb
3 | cc

Table 2

id field1 field2

1 | works in | New York
1 | likes to go to | Paris

As you see, each row represents an entity related to entity with id 1 and which value corresponds which matters.

How do I achieve this with Solr's data import handler?

I used SubEntity in data-config.xml and multiValued=true for field1 and field2, but the indexed document looks like

id 1
field1:[works in, likes to go to]
field2:[New York, Paris]

and the relationships between columns were completely lost. If one searches works in Paris he can also get entity 1. What should I do to maintain the relationships? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Schema Definition in schema.xml

**id**(type string)
**name**(type string)
**worksIn** (type string, multi value= true) - your choice if multi-value required or not
**likesToGo** (type string, multi value= true) - multivalue makes sense here as person is,most likely have more places to go, anyways your requirement

**Sample docs after indexing**

1,aa, worksIn[Newyork, New Jeysey], likesToGo[Paris, Moon]
2,bb, worksIn[Dallas], likesToGo[NewYork, Sun]

**Querying**

For "works in Paris", query is "worksIn:Paris".
You get doc with id 1
For "likes to go to sun", query is "likesToGo:sun".
You get doc with id 2